# Adding data to a table dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add rows to a table dynamically but it concatenates the data of both textboxes then add it to the first `<td>`, what could be the problem?

```js
function AddDataToTable() {
  var id = document.getElementById("id1").value;
  var firstname = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
  var trNode = document.createElement("tr");
  var tdNode = document.createElement("td");
  trNode.appendChild(tdNode);
  var trID = document.createTextNode(id);
  var trFirstName = document.createTextNode(firstname);
  tdNode.appendChild(trID);
  tdNode.appendChild(trFirstName);
  document.getElementById("productable").appendChild(trNode);
}
```

```html
<table id="productable" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Item</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Shoes</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br/>
<input type="text" name="id" id="id1">
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname">
<input type="button" onclick="AddDataToTable()" value="Add" />
```

Comment: You can create a code snippet like jsfiddle but directly on SO.

Comment: @EmileBergeron alright thanks.

Comment: Well, you’re creating only one `<td>`. `tdNode` are not two table cells.

Comment: I would also use names that make sense. Like `firstname` for the item name?!

Comment: @Xufox great! thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Need to create two `td` elements and append the text node twice respective to them.

```js
function AddDataToTable() {
  var productable = document.getElementById("productable");
  var id = document.getElementById("id1").value;
  var firstname = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
  var trNode = document.createElement("tr");
  // creating a delete button.
  var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  btn.innerHTML = 'delete';
  btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    
    productable.removeChild(trNode);
  });
  
  var tdNode1 = document.createElement("td");
  var tdNode2 = document.createElement("td");
  trNode.appendChild(tdNode1);
  trNode.appendChild(tdNode2);
  trNode.appendChild(btn);
  var trID = document.createTextNode(id);
  var trFirstName = document.createTextNode(firstname);
  tdNode1.appendChild(trID);
  tdNode2.appendChild(trFirstName);
  document.getElementById("productable").appendChild(trNode);
}
```

```css
#productable,
th,
td {
  border: 1px dotted grey;
}
td {
  padding: 20px;
}
th {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<title>Table</title>

<body>
  <table id="productable">
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Item</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Shoes</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br/>
  <input type="text" name="id" id="id1">
  <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname">
  <input type="button" onclick="AddDataToTable()" value="Add" />
</body>
```

Comment: how can we add delete button for that? :and edit also? :)

Comment: @Nevi You wanna delete by Id , say u enter an id and click delete, it deletes the particular row, correct?

Comment: @EmileBergeron indeed :)

Comment: @Nevi I have attached a delete button which removes the tr child from DOM. Need to brush up the css.